# Run a sub on another multi-instance form VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, subroutine, basic

I have a tabbed form layout application (VB.net) which a particular form has a datagridview that opens a particular record in another form. The forms are opened as follows;

```
public sub OpenRecord() 'Reference. Part of a bigger routine (On Orgional form)
    Dim NewSnagWindow As New Maint_SnagCard
    NewSnagWindow.SentFrom = Me
    MaintraxTabFunctions.TAB_OpenNewTabedForm(Main, NewSnagWindow)

End Sub

Public Sub RefreshDGV()
    'Refresh the DGV here
End sub

Public Shared Function TAB_OpenNewTabedForm(sender As System.Object, NewForm As Windows.Forms.Form, Optional AsTab As Boolean = True) As Form

    If AsTab Then
        Dim NewTab As New TabPage
        NewForm.TopLevel = False
        NewForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        NewForm.Parent = NewTab
        NewForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        NewForm.Visible = True
        NewTab.Text = NewForm.Text
        NewTab.Name = NewForm.Name
        sender.TabPlane.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
        sender.TabPlane.SelectedTab = NewTab
    Else
        NewForm.Show()
    End If
    Return NewForm
End Function
```

I want; on closing of the New form (NewSnagWindow) to fire the RefreshDGV() sub on the origional form (MaintRecords.Frm). I have tried multiple ways of calling this Eg: Looking for all instances of MaintRecords (The browser form) and attempting to fire it etc, and i just cant get it to work.

The latest attempt on the NewSnagForm was:

```
Public SentFrom As Object    '### SentForm set as 'me' on origional sender form.

Private Sub SaveAndCloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveAndCloseButton.Click

'Do some Saving Data tasks and magic

    SentFrom.RefreshDGV()
End sub
```

I just cannot get it to fire no matter what i do. Any ideas anyone? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just sharing an idea. Add a module and inside the module declare a public boolean variable. Now on "Dispose" event of "NewForm" set the boolean variable as true. And in the "GotFocus" event of "MainRecords" form check if the boolean is "True" then fire RefreshDGV and after that set the boolean to "False". Let me know if it works.

Comment: Good idea, but no, the forms .GotFocus event isnt firing. I think its because the forms/tab behavior. The form is made a child of the tab page and set to dock/fill. Somehow thats interrupting the Got Focus event. (because the Tab actually got the focus? dunno). It gives me the idea of trying to get the tabpages got focus....or tab changed thou, but iv had no luck with that so far. Thanks.

Comment: Then try "Activate" event or A form/control must firing the GotFocus event. You just have to find which one. A useful link -> http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=141926 Main content is "When you switch between two open forms, the Deactivate event occurs for the first form, and the Activate event occurs for the second form. If the forms contain no visible, enabled controls, the LostFocus event occurs for the first form before the Deactivate event, and the GotFocus event occurs for the second form after the Activate event."

Comment: Found a solution: add "AddHandler Main.TabPlane.GotFocus, AddressOf Me.RefreshDGV" to the form.load of the browser form. Main is the actual main form that holds the 'TpbPlane' (tab control) that the forms are drawn in. Its drity, but its working.

Comment: Congratulation Josh

Comment: Iv checked .activated and .gotfocus on everything from the Browser form, the tabpages, the controls on the form, nothing is firing Except fro the TabControl that holds the forms .GotFocus. The forms parent.gotfocus isnt firing either. (the parent being the TabPage that holds the form.)

Comment: Thanks for the link, Helpful info.

Comment: I Have used your idea to control the form from refreshing the data everytime any other form/tab is closed. So thanks.

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might be a solution for you:

```
' Main form
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub RefreshDGV(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("RefreshDGV")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim f As New Form2
        f.Show(Me)
    End Sub

End Class


' Child form
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler FormClosing, AddressOf Form1.RefreshDGV
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Its close, and normally would have worked from what I'm figuring out now, however the way I have done the forms in tabs are obviously interrupting all the forms events, therefore they are not firing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have come up with is as follows:

The tabed forms are disrupting the forms events so I was unable to use them so, in the main form (that holds the tab panel) I have;

```
Public Class Main
    Public RefreshMaintCards as Boolean = False
    '.....
End Class
```

On the MainCards form (The one that needs to be refreshed on the close of the 3rd form)...

```
Public Class MaintRecords
 Private Sub MaintRecords_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Main.TabPlane.GotFocus, AddressOf Me.RefreshTest
 End Sub

 Private Sub RefreshTest()
    If Main.RefreshOpReq Then
        RefreshDGV()
        Main.RefreshMaintCards = False
    End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub RefreshDGV()
     '.....Do Refresh
 End Sub
End Class
```

And Finally on the Closing Form (The one I want to fire the RefreshDGV when closing....

```
Private Sub SaveAndCloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveAndCloseButton.Click

    Main.RefreshMaintCards = True

    TabFunctions.CloseME(Me) 'Closes the tab
End Sub
```

The purpose of the RefreshTest() is just to stop the sub RefreshDGV() firing when other tabs are closed. (Just reduce data xfer overheads)